# category filter to admin product grid with distinct records (using group breaks pagination)

Tags: magento

i have added category filter to admin grid which is working, below is the code

```
$cat_ids = implode(',', $CatIdArray['CategoryId']);
$collection->getSelect()
         ->join(array('ccp'=>'catalog_category_product'),
            "ccp.product_id = e.entity_id AND ccp.category_id IN({$cat_ids})",
            array('category_id')
         );
```

Now the problem is when multiple category have same product it crashes, to avoid that
i used

```
$collection->groupByAttribute('entity_id');
```

which returns me distinct record but this breaks paginaion. i know this is common issue but any help will be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of

```
$collection->groupByAttribute('entity_id');
```

use this

```
$collection->getSelect()->group('entity_id');
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are facing group by issue.I solve the same problem multiple time using this way .
Copy Db.php file from magento / lib / Varien / Data / Collection / Db.php
Paste it to your local directory so the resultant folder structure would look like this:
magento `/ app / code / local / Varien / Data / Collection / Db.php`.
Now open this file to edit and replace getSelectCountSql function with below one

```
public function getSelectCountSql()
    {
        $this->_renderFilters();

        $countSelect = clone $this->getSelect();
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);

        if(count($this->getSelect()->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP)) > 0) {
            $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
            $countSelect->distinct(true);
            $group = $this->getSelect()->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
            $countSelect->columns("COUNT(DISTINCT ".implode(", ", $group).")");
        } else {
            $countSelect->columns('COUNT(*)');
        }
        return $countSelect;
    }.Try this , hope this will help you.
```